# How to know if a thread is on the wait queue

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, debugging, windbg

If you didn't have the source code, then other than by looking at its callstack (`k` or `!sosex.mk` or `!clrstack` or `!eestack`), is there a way to tell that a thread is presently in the *wait queue* waiting for something to happen, like waiting to receive an I/O interrupt or a notification from an I/O completion port?

Or may be just a sleeping thread not waiting *on* anything but one that is still on the wait queue nevertheless?

To test, I made a small C# program in which I made a thread sleep for 20 seconds.

```
main()
{
  Thread.Sleep(20000);
}
```

While I attached Windbg to its process. And checked its thread state and the sleeping thread reported a thread state of `0x202a020`:

```
00:00> !threadstate 202a020
Legal to Join
CoInitialized
In Multi Threaded Apartment
Fully initialized
Interruptible
```

I understand each of the state flags except I am not very clear about the last one, i.e. *Interruptible*. My guess is that the *Interruptible* flag simply indicates that the thread may be interrupted by any kernel level interrupt but does not necessarily indicate that it is on the wait queue. Even a running state thread could be interrupted, right?

So, is there a foolproof method to know whether a thread is presently on the wait queue or not? Or even if it is on the *ready queue* but not running yet?

Comment: What about checking `thread.ThreadState`? It will be in `WaitSleepJoin` state in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add "from the outside if you didn't have the source code." I'll just update the question.

Comment: @Evk Actually, that's a brilliant idea. If I can get a hold of its Thread class (the managed) object, I could read its `!mdt` or `!do`. Let me give that a try.

Comment: I got the method table address, then the method description for the `get_ThreadState()` property accessor for the main thread object, but it won't let me do a `.call System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState` or `.call System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.get_ThreadState()`. Do you know a way I can invoke a method if I know the address of its IL or its native code?

Comment: You can only call a method in live debugging. It won't work for crash dumps.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, I attached Windbg to the live process. It still did not let me `.call`. Have you been able to use `.call` to invoke a managed method in a live debugging session?